# Dangerous Cast?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
   protected:
       void some_function(int params)
       {
        //inside A: do something A related 
       }
};

class B: public A{
public:
    void call_some_function(int params)
    {
    some_function(params); // Simple call to A::some_function and NOTHING MORE.
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   A* a = new A();

   ((B*)(a))->call_some_function(20); // Is it OK ?
}
```

This code works 
What is the danger of using it ?

Comment: Declare `virtual void call_some_function(int params)` and your code will magically stop working.

Comment: What if the point of declaring it is to access the protected or a private member of class A and make it available to program, Is it OK in such case ?

Comment: Make class B a friend. Derive from A, but create objects of type B, not A. Make public calls in A if you need it. Use plain functions. Anything, but don't use OOP if you're going to break it.

In general, code that works != code is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One danger is that `call_some_function` can only call functions (or access members in general) in `A`. All access to a member of `B` will result in access outside of allocated memory, with probably disastrous consequences.

Comment: Yeh but for this specific scenario when the point of defining the class B is to access a protected member in A. Is it ok to do like that ?

Comment: @Orochi In this case, using `B` as a proxy for `A` it might be ok. But usage like this should definitively an exception and not a rule.

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++, it is generally *undefined behaviour* (read this as "illegal but allowed by compiler") to dereference an object of one type through a pointer or reference to an object of another type (with few exceptions like accessing via a pointer to a base class). This is called the **strict aliasing rule.**

Read more here: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Your code violates this rule by accessing an object of type A through the pointer to type B.

---

Note that generally the compiler isn't able to verify your static casts (in your case the C-cast is equivalent to a `static_cast`). If you aren't sure of the object type, `dynamic_cast` to verify if the cast is legal during runtime, as opposed to `static_cast` which is checked only at compile time and allows some incorrect casts.

Comment: Actually "undefined behavior" should be read as "Illegal and NEVER DO THIS".

Comment: Well that depends ]:>, but case of this specific issue, I absolutely agree.

Comment: Yeh i agree this, but is it really that unpredictable ? If the code remains like this and we do not do more inheritance of class A and B then the point of doing this will be to access protected or private member through such syntax without declaring an object explicitly

Comment: You can just [#define protected public](https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl/blob/master/neo/game/Game_local.h) and get the same result. The question is: Why would you even need to?! It either belongs to the interface (make it public) or doesn't (make it private). Don't over-complicate your code.

Comment: yeh i agree about over-complication 
But #define protected public will be very global kind of replacement :)
I know this is prone to error but, is there any better option to do it without overriding all functions of class A which are declared virtual and must be overridden in B. By doing this i am saving a lot of redundant coding. i.e. B is not even declared and the (static) case is serving as a passage way to the protected member function.

Comment: Long story: Don't make that thing private if it needs to be public. Short story: Redesign.

Answer (score 1):

The danger is that having a pointer to `A`, you're normally not sure if it's `B` or `C` derived class instance.

Comment: This answer is too generalized, you should also explain why it works [I did not use c++ for a while, but from what I remember, I think it has something to do with `some_function()` not being `virtual`, and the fact that both A and B do not have any fields.

Comment: As an aside, using C style casting with C++ code is really gross. Try looking into dynamic/static casting.

Comment: @amit, the problem is too general, the cast itself is bad, not necessarily with virtual function. The data pointed to doesn't necessarily meet expectations.

Comment: I agree the C Style cast and etc is bad programming practice. But the point is the declaration is there to provide an access to the protected member "without declaring an explicit object of B". Now one thing is clear "it is allowed and work". The real question is, is it dangerous to do such referencing for accessing a class with such a cast in order to escape the explicit declaration of B object.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly - depends on how the compiler arranges memory for objects.

C++ is a language that gives more than enough rope to hang yourself with and eveybody else in the room!

My point of view is that you should use casts as little as possible and only on rare occasions.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior, so anything could happen.  In practice, you
might get away with it as long as only single inheritance is involved,
but in general, you can't count on it; a debugging implementation could,
for example, generate code in `B::call_some_function` to ensure that the
address passed as `this` corresponds to an object of type `B` that
actually exists in the program.

Comment: So that means is it "safe" if i do not have any member variables in B and i don't do more inheritance ?

Comment: No.  It means that you're likely to get away with it for the moment.

Comment: But what could go wrong if the motive is to access the private or protected member function only ?

Comment: Anything the implementer wants to go wrong.  That's what undefined behavior means.  I already pointed out one possibility: a debugging version of the compiler could generate verification code.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the code only *appears* to work. You've invoked undefined behavior by telling the compiler you have a `B` when you really only have an `A` (parent class). It could break at any time, even with the same compiler.

Comment: That's interesting, do you think it will still have a chance to break even if the code remains same and nothing else is added to it ?

Answer (score 0):

The dengures is in scenario like this (and I'm sure some more):

```
class B: public A{
public:

    int local_var;

    void call_some_function(int params)
    {
        local_var = 5; // IN HERE.
        some_function(params); // Simple call to A::some_function and NOTHING MORE.
    }
};
```

In this case it will try to access an undefined var (local_var).

It's like:

```
struct A {
int i1;
int i2;
}

struct B {
int i1;
int i2;
int i3;
}

A a;
(B)a.i1 = 2;
```

it will work (most likely) but it's bad practice and basically undefined code.